# Opencv Segmentation Fault using pthread to capture frames C++

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, pthreads, opencv3.0

I am receiving a segmentation fault when trying to run my program. I am only receiving segmentation faults after modifying my program to capture frames from two cameras on separate threads. I am using the same function on both threads and I am wondering if this is the problem.

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "ThreadedWebcamCapture.h"

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main(){
    ThreadedCapture Capture1;
    Capture1.STOP = 0;
    Capture1.CAP_NUMBER = 1;
    Capture1.X_RESOLUTION = 640;
    Capture1.Y_RESOLUTION = 480;

    ThreadedCapture Capture2;
    Capture2.STOP = 0;
    Capture2.CAP_NUMBER = 0;
    Capture2.X_RESOLUTION = 640;
    Capture2.Y_RESOLUTION = 480;

    pthread_t Capture1Thread;
    int Capture1ThreadRetCode;

    pthread_t Capture2Thread;
    int Capture2ThreadRetCode;

    printf("[INFO]Creating Threads\n");
    Capture1ThreadRetCode = pthread_create(&Capture1Thread, NULL, &Capture_Thread, (void *)&Capture1);
    printf("[INFO]Created Thread 1");
    Capture2ThreadRetCode = pthread_create(&Capture2Thread, NULL, &Capture_Thread, (void *)&Capture2); //I think the error is occurring here
    if(Capture1ThreadRetCode || Capture2ThreadRetCode != 0){
        printf("[ERROR]Thread Creation Failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //cv::namedWindow("Window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    int NumberOfFrames;
    time_t Seconds1;
    Seconds1 = time(NULL);
    cv::Mat Output;
    while(1 == 1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        if(!Capture1.FRAME.empty() || !Capture2.FRAME.empty()){
            cv::hconcat(Capture1.FRAME, Capture2.FRAME, Output);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        if(!Output.empty()){
            NumberOfFrames = NumberOfFrames + 1;
            cv::imshow("Window", Output);
        }
        if(cv::waitKeyEx(1) >= 0){
            Capture1.STOP = 1;
            Capture2.STOP = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    time_t Seconds2;
    Seconds2 = time(NULL);
    int Seconds = Seconds2 - Seconds1;
    int FPS = NumberOfFrames / Seconds;
    printf("[INFO]FPS %d\n", FPS);
    pthread_join(Capture1Thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(Capture2Thread, NULL);
    printf("[INFO]Done\n");
    return(0);
}
```

cvthreads.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "ThreadedWebcamCapture.h"

void *Capture_Thread(void* Test){
    ThreadedCapture *Testing = (ThreadedCapture *) Test;
    cv::VideoCapture CAP ((*Testing).CAP_NUMBER);
    CAP.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, (*Testing).X_RESOLUTION);
    CAP.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, (*Testing).Y_RESOLUTION);
    while((*Testing).STOP != 1){
        CAP.read((*Testing).FRAME);
    }
    return(NULL);
}
```

ThreadedWebcamCapture.h

```
#ifndef _THREADEDWEBCAMCAPTURE_H_
#define _THREADEDWEBCAMCAPTURE_H_

void *Capture_Thread(void* Test);

typedef struct ThreadedCaptures  {
    int STOP;
    int CAP_NUMBER;
    int X_RESOLUTION;
    int Y_RESOLUTION;
    cv::Mat FRAME;
} ThreadedCapture;

#endif
```

Comment: Can you run the program in a debugger and tell us which line of your code leads to segfault? You might even paste the whole stacktrace.

Comment: This is the error i get when I run it but when I run it in gdb it doesn't have a fault.

Comment: *** Error in `./app': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f30d0001a40 ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: The output of strace is here https://pastebin.com/06ZiA2vc

Comment: Just a wild first guess but Posix does not like to let you call pthread_mutex_init more than once and you use the static initialization already for the mutex. Here is what Posix says about calling it more than once:

"Attempting to initialise an already initialised mutex results in undefined behaviour. "

Comment: As @rolfwinter said, can you make your mutex a local variable inside main? Right now, you dont need it to be a global variable. Further, you don't need to init your mutex at each iteration. Initialize it when you create it, only once. Also, as a side comment, the if statement at the beginning where you test for nonzero return codes is probably not what you want; it works, but in a weird way.

Comment: I did not really say to make it a local variable. Keeping it global is alright and makes it easily accessible to each thread, just do not initialize it more than once.

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing the big picture, but it looks like that mutex is useless right now. It is  locked, and then the data is read, and then the mutex is unlocked, which is fine, but I believe its purpose is synchronizing writer thread that opencv capture object runs on and the reader threads used in this example. It looks like writer thread has no knowledge of the mutex.

Comment: I thought I only had to lock the variable in one of the threads if it was only accessed by two threads because otherwise they both try to lock at once and cause the program to hang

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `cv::hconcat` function, specifically with passing two `cv::Mat` objects with different number of rows. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf9771c991763233866bf76b5b5d1776f) of `cv::hconcat` function, it says the given two matrices must have the same number of rows. You can also see that in the last lines of your strace result, there is an assertion error stating that number of rows sent to `cv::hconcat` weren't equal.

`"OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ("..., 205OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src[i].dims <= 2 && src[i].rows == src[0].rows && src[i].type() == src[0].type()) in hconcat, file /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2865`

Now, the reason for this error is in these lines:

```
if(!Capture1.FRAME.empty() || !Capture2.FRAME.empty()){
    cv::hconcat(Capture1.FRAME, Capture2.FRAME, Output);
}
```

You perform the horizontal concatenation operation if any of the matrices is not empty. However, this implies that one of the matrices may have size 640x480 and the other may have 0x0. In that case, `cv::hconcat` throws an assertion error and your program crashes. To fix it, try changing the condition to

```
if(!Capture1.FRAME.empty() && !Capture2.FRAME.empty()){
    cv::hconcat(Capture1.FRAME, Capture2.FRAME, Output);
}
```

so that you perform the operation only when both of the matrices are not empty. They should have the same number of rows since you build your `ThreadedCapture` objects with the same number of rows.

### References

- https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf9771c991763233866bf76b5b5d1776f

Comment: I am still getting a segmentation fault when the program starts but that is only sometimes so I must have another issue in my code i will run strace on it again.

Comment: Have you tried removing ``pthread_mutex_init`` calls from your loop?

Comment: Yes I removed that line completly and now the program runs sometimes I have updated the code above to reflect the changes about pthread_mutex_init